# Создать файл .json виртуально

Tags: c#, json, файлы, сериализация, asp.net-core-webapi

Есть коллекция которую я сериализую в json в беке

```
var json = JsonConverter.Serialize(collection);
```

Была поставлена задача изменить метод так чтобы он возвращал не сериализованную строку с данными внутри а файл .json формата и вернул его таким фронту с именем. Но загвоздка в том что нельзя создавать на беке файл и размещать его где либо, нужно сделать так будто передал реальный файл во фронт, но без его создания. Есть какие то варианты решения задачи? Желательно с примерами реализации.

Comment: А если вот так? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: не, надо именно файл

Comment: я понимаю что по ссылке можно будет скачать, но нужен сам файл во фронт отправить

Comment: [Оно](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-files-from-web-api/)?

Comment: Честно, не уверен, это похоже но то что выше, по ссылке

Comment: А мне кажется, оно. Вы можете создать из сериализованной строки `StringContent` и отдать его как `attachement`, дав имя файла `file.json`.

Comment: Если вы уверены, можете оформить как ответ и получить лойс от меня))

Comment: Я уверен только в технической составляющей. Для какого типа приложения это вам надо и в каком окружении вы это делаете - я не знаю. Теги для типа приложения вы не проставили, в тексте вопроса тоже ничего нет. Следовательно и ответ оформить в принципе невозможно. Но вы можете оформить ответ сами, если желаете поделиться с сообществом своим решением.

Comment: Asp.Net Core 5 Web Api

Comment: Вот теперь если придет специалист по этой платформе, то даст ответ. Я не шарю в ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
{
    // Помещаем данные в стрим

    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    var collection = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    new JsonSerializer().Serialize(writer, collection);

    // Используем стрим

    var content = new StreamContent(stream);

    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "data.json";

    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    message.Content = content;

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за ответ. Тут случаем ошибки нет никакой? содержимое пустое.

Answer (score 2):

Просто возвращайте [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult).

Answer (score 1):

Помог вот этот вариант решения задачи

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection);
byte[] masByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
return File(masByte, "application/json", $"namefile_{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy}.json");
```